# (Magento2) How to change template of category page depending on category level?

Tags: magento2.2

I want my level 0 category to have a different layout from level 1,2...How can I do this by code or by admin page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add below code at admin category settings under "Layout Update XML":

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
   <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">YourPackage_YourModule::path/to/file.phtml</argument>
    </action>
   </referenceBlock>
</referenceContainer>
```

if you are simply trying in any xml file then you can update by below code:

```
<referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">YourPackage_YourModule::path/to/file.phtml</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```